gstreamer sending both video and audio via "udpsink"
I managed to mux both audio and video streams and save them into a single MP4 file using GStreamer. For example:
gst-launch-1.0 -v \
  videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! h264parse ! mpegtsmux name=mux ! filesink location=output.mp4 \
  audiotestsrc ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! avenc_aac ! aacparse ! mux.

However, when I attempted to split this process into two parts – sender and receiver – I encountered issues with the receiver part. Here's how I'm sending it:
Sender:
gst-launch-1.0 -v \
  videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! h264parse ! mpegtsmux name=mux ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000 \
  audiotestsrc ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! avenc_aac ! aacparse ! mux.

I also tried to simplify it by just sending either the video or audio stream, but didn't manage to get it to work hence I am here hoping someone will help... Any guidance on how to properly set up the receiver would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Note: The process involves streaming, and it's important for me to splitmuxsink the data into smaller MP4 files. Additionally, I don't necessarily need to use udpsink, as long as the data can be transferred over the network."

I have tried various suggestions since then. For example, below is one attempt where I tested sending only video:
gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! h264parse ! mpegtsmux name=mux ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000

For the receiver part, something like this:
gst-launch-1.0 -v -e  udpsrc port=5000 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264" ! rtpjitterbuffer ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! mp4mux ! filesink location=/tmp/received_video.mp4

I added -e to include end-of-stream (EOS) signaling, also tried switching between different muxers. However, some attempts resulted in the generated MP4 file having a size of 0 bytes, while others produced files with content that were unable to play.
UPDATE
I made some progress and got video and audio to work individually via udpsink:
Video Sender
gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc ! x264enc key-int-max=30 ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000

Video Receiver
gst-launch-1.0 -v -e udpsrc port=5000 \
  caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264" \
  ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! splitmuxsink location=/tmp/output-rtsp-%05d.mp4 max-size-time=1000000000

Audio Sender
gst-launch-1.0 audiotestsrc \
  ! audioconvert \
  ! audioresample \
  ! mulawenc \
  ! rtppcmupay \
  ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000

Audio Receiver
gst-launch-1.0 -v -e udpsrc port=5000 \
   ! 'application/x-rtp,media=audio,payload=96,clock-rate=44100,encoding-name=L24' \
   ! rtpL24depay \
   ! audioconvert \
   ! audioresample \
   ! avenc_aac \
   ! aacparse \
   ! mux.audio_0 splitmuxsink name=mux location=out_%d.mp4 max-size-time=1000000000

I still have some problem combining the receivers so that each MP4 file contains both video and audio...any help would be great
